# image zoomin-zoomout functionality

Tags: html, fancybox, zooming

I have designed website, in this used FancyBox version 2.1.4. Now I want to implement Zoom in and Zoom out functionality, this is having FancyBox version 1.3.4. I  have integrated this with website but not getting proper effect, it doesn't give me Zoom in and out options

Comment: fancybox v1.3.4 doesn't have the same functionality as v2.1.4 and zomm functionality is not included in the older version. I guess if you have to custom code it yourself (if you know how to do that)

Comment: I have tried and zoom in functionality available on fancybox v1.3.4.

Comment: can u please help me... if you are having solution can you please provide me

Comment: I guess I misread your question. If what you want are "transition" effects for fancybox v1.3.4, use `transitionIn` and `transitionOut` http://jsfiddle.net/56nmg/1/

Comment: Yes, but i am not able to merge these both versions... What can i do next?

Comment: Okay. If u have any other script to image zoom in-out which i can surely add with fancybox v2.1.4 ? Can u please share with me

Comment: If you are talking about effects, then check `openEffect/closeEffect`, otherwise check the buttons helper (to toggle images from scaled size to normal (big) size) ...fancybox v2.x

Comment: I have tried some other scripts too, but that were not working with image zoomin